# Simulating non-stationary processes

Tags: r, time-series, simulation

arima.sim() works like a charm for simulating a stationary time series, but I can't find any built-ins or packages that simulate a non-stationary time series parameterized by otherwise arbitrary arima coefficients. Does anything like this exist already, or is this one of those things I'll just have to code up manually?

Comment: best way to implement this is simply to get the code for arima.sim (which you can do by just inputting ```arima.sim``` without parenthesis), switch the "stop" command with a warning and setting a sensible n.start formula (like ```p+q``` without the ceiling bit); also, if you use a lot of tidyverse stuff you might want to be extra safe and replace the ```filter``` commands in arima.sim with ```stats::filter```

Answer (score 0):

For example, we want to simulate an AR(1) process, with φ = -1.1, defined as: X_t=μ+ϕX_{t−1}+Z_t

```
set.seed(123456) # creo una semilla 
Xt <- filter(rnorm(100), filter = c(-1.1), method='recursive')
ar1.Xt <- ar.ols(Xt, intercept = T)
ar1.Xt
plot(ar1.Xt, xlim = c(-1.2,1.2), ylim = c(-1.2,1.2))
```

The inverse roots are outside the unit circle, and therefore it is a non-stationary process

[image]

Answer (score -1):

`arima.sim()` handles non-stationary series. There is even an example in the help file to show you how to do it.

It does not, however, handle seasonal ARIMA models. For that you should use the `simulate.Arima` function from the `forecast` package.

Comment: Thanks Rob - I must be missing something obvious. I don't see anything explicit in the help file that mentions non-stationary models, except this:

`Other aspects of the order component are ignored, but inconsistent specifications of the MA and AR orders are detected.`

I receive an error whenever I try. eg:

`Error in arima.sim(list(order = c(1, 0, 0), ar = 1), n = 1000) : 
  'ar' part of model is not stationary`

Comment: The last example in the help file is an ARIMA simulation: `ts.sim <- arima.sim(list(order = c(1,1,0), ar = 0.7), n = 200)`. Your example is problematic because you have set the first ar coefficient to 1.

Comment: How to simulate a time series that has AR coefficients of 0.5, 0.8, and -0.4, for example? Or AR coefficients of 1.2 and -0.5? arima.sim would throw an error for both of these examples, claiming them to be nonstationary.

Comment: Either re-write the model in a standard ARIMA format where the non-stationarity is handled via the differencing and AR part is stationary, or write your own function. With an AR model it will take about 3 lines of code.